# Why do I get an error saying I must be privileged to use `crontab -u`?

Tags: command-line, cron

I am trying to list all the cron jobs for all the users in my Ubuntu system using the following command:

```bsh
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done
```

Why am I getting the following error:

```
must be privileged to use this -u
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't have the necessary permissions to read other users' crontabs, either run as `root` or use `sudo` to invoke `crontab -u`, e.g.

```bsh
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do sudo crontab -u $user -l; done
```

or

```bsh
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | xargs -n1 sudo crontab -lu
```